# getting TypeError in console when clicking the ok and cancel buttons in modal.

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap-modal

I am using the angular ui modal model to make my modal service. Everything works except when clicking on the ok and cancel buttons, console tells me 
    TypeError: $uibModal.dismiss is not a function
    at Scope.ModalController.$scope.cancel (table-todos-modal.controller.js:21)

here is my modal controller.

```
(function() {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('chamAppApp.table-todos')
    .controller('ModalController', ModalController);

ModalController.$inject = ['$scope', '$uibModal', 'items'];

/* @ngInject */
function ModalController($scope, $uibModal, items) {

    $scope.title = 'ModalController';
    $scope.category = items;

    $scope.ok = function() {
        $uibModal.close();
    };

    $scope.cancel = function() {
        $uibModal.dismiss('cancel');
    };

    activate();

    ////////////////

    function activate() {
        console.log('checking if this works');
    }
}
})();
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a `$modalInstance` to call `.dismiss()` and `.ok()`.

Here is a complete **working example** for you:

http://plnkr.co/edit/6djuhA8ohMkrWW7zohg1?p=preview

You should do something like this in order to make it work.

```
var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
    animation: $scope.animationsEnabled,
    templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
    controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
    size: size,
    resolve: {
        items: function () {
            return $scope.items;
        }
    }
});

modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedItem) {
    $scope.selected = selectedItem;
}, function () {
    $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I added the $modalInstance dependency and now it all works.

Comment: No problem at all. Anytime :) If possible please upvote the answer as well so others can know it is useful. Thank you